# How to preset Parse fields?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

https://www.flickr.com/photos/dom497/16118311866/

Based off the picture linked above, here's the scenario: A user signs-up in my app and their data is added to Parse. How can I get `ElginSupAccess` to be preset to `false`?

I've tried using the following to update the field but apparently I cannot update an undefined field. (using Swift)

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"_User")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(nameID) {
            (update: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

            update["elginSupAccess"] = false
            update.saveEventually()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dom,

In Parse the correct syntax of querying the user class is below, you don't query it by class name:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
```

or for swift

```
var query = PFUser.query()
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("xWMyZEGZ") { 
(update: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
if error != nil {
NSLog("%@", error)
} else {
update["ElginSupAccess"] = false
}
```

Comment: Ya but "_User" shouldn't make a difference....I know, it's technically not the best way but it works. I use it all over my app. I'm just running into an error for this instance.

Comment: @dom999999 it kinda does make a difference. Have you tried it

Comment: The thing about doing it the way you want is your not going to know the users object ID until after they sign up and then you'll have to manually change it in the for every user. For testing purposes it will work because you know what your test username and object. ID. You won't know everyone else's until after they have signed up

Comment: I have the object id worked out. That's not the issue. (Immediately after registration, I fetch the user object ID and save it to core data. On the view controllers that I need the user ID, I just get it from Core Data...hence the variable "nameID")

Comment: I also tried using PFUser but I still get a nil value

Comment: I figured out the issue. I'll give the check mark for trying to help me :)